# Extjs 7.5.0 colorfield in RTL

Tags: extjs

does colorfield have bugs in rtl?
If yes, is there an alternative?
Because after using this field, the shape of the page will be messed up and you can see the photo [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wda0.png)

I just used its X-type exactly like the examples in the document itself

```
                    xtype:'colorfield',
                    value: '#993300',  // initial selected color

                    listeners : {
                        change: function(field, color) {
                            console.log('New color: ' + color);
                        }
                    },
```

If anyone has ever encountered this problem and was able to solve it, thank you for guiding me.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Please setup this fiddle, so that it reproduces the error: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3it89

Comment: @Dinkheller Thanks for the answer, the error I was able to get in the console section was "Layout run failed" but in the ltr section I can use it without any error, I will try to fill in the fiddel for you and send it to you.